# Getting POST requests Django Python

Tags: python, django

I have Django framework on my site, and I need to **receive post** requests from the user.

So, how I can do this, and how may I process this request(etc, after getting post request, pull this data)

Answer (score 1):

With a view function:

**views.py**

```py
def my_view_function(request):

    # unpack request:
    some_value = request.POST.get('some_key')

    # do something:
    ...

    # send response:
    return JsonResponse({
        'status_code' : 200,
        'message' : 'OK'
    })
```